# jQuery is picking up the value for first textarea only, not others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've multiple textarea's with same class but differ ids & data-ref for my own reference.
I am using the following jQuery script to get the data on keypress (enter)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(document).on('keypress', '.comment-text',function(e){

        var key = e.which;
        if(key == 13)
        {
           e.preventDefault();
           var post_id = $(".comment-text").data('ref');
           var comment_text = $("#comment" + post_id).val();
       // or i can use the var comment_text = $(".comment-text").val();
       //both gives the same result
           console.log(comment_text);
           if(comment_text.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '') === '')
           {
             $('.comment-text').val('');
             $('.comment-text').blur();
           }     
           else 
       {
        $("#no-comment").hide('fast');
        $('ul.post-id-'+ post_id).prepend('<li class="list-group-item"><a   href="/username/" class="text-dark"><b>username</b></a> '+ comment_text +' <span class="text-muted">Just Now</span></li>');
       $('.comment-text').val('');
       $('.comment-text').blur();
     return false; // Just a workaround for old browsers
           }


        }


      });

});
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment-write">
   <ul class="list-group post-id04">


    <li id="#no-comment">No Comment Yet</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<textarea class="comment-text" data-ref="04" id="comment04" placeholder="Enter comment.."></textarea>
```

But it is working for the first textarea only, not for multiple/dynamic input.

Comment: try changing `var post_id = $(".comment-text").data('ref');` to `var post_id = $(this).data('ref');`, so that you are getting the clicked on `data-ref`

Comment: its working,,,,thanku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead of class name to get current **textarea** value. change your code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(document).on('keypress', '.comment-text',function(e){

        var key = e.which;
        if(key == 13)
        {
           e.preventDefault();
           var post_id = $(this).data('ref');
           var comment_text = $(this).val();
       // or i can use the var comment_text = $(".comment-text").val();
       //both gives the same result
            console.log(comment_text);
           if(comment_text.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '') === '')
           {
             $(this).val('');
             $(this).blur();
           }     
           else 
       {
        $("#no-comment").hide('fast');
        $('ul.post-id-'+ post_id).prepend('<li class="list-group-item"><a   href="/username/" class="text-dark"><b>username</b></a> '+ comment_text +' <span class="text-muted">Just Now</span></li>');
       $(this).val('');
       $(this).blur();
     return false; // Just a workaround for old browsers
           }


        }


      });

});
```